# Gutters above Garage Door on slanted driveway - is it necessary?

Tags: doors, garage, gutters

The concrete driveway attached to my garage which is attached to my home is on a slant.  The water runs away from the home to the alley. I'm getting gutters installed for the first time. Do I need to have gutters above the garage door?  Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. What problem are you trying to solve? As it is you've asked for opinions without much context, which makes the question off topic.

Answer (score 2):

- Water pouring off the roof will be an annoyance when you're driving or walking in/out of the garage door.
- Water pouring off the roof will damage the concrete (take a look at the Grand Canyon if you're not convinced what water can do).
- Despite the slope, water will splash, puddle and eventually get its way into your garage.

Yes, you should go ahead and get the gutters installed above the garage door. For the small additional cost, it's well worth it, IMHO.

Comment: "Need" and "should" are two different realms. I agree, but it's not clear what's being asked.

Comment: Reasonable point, @isherwood. Amazing how we all see different things in different questions. I've noted a couple of similar issues earlier today as opinion-based, but didn't see it in this one. That's why we all work together.